# How can I access java static field in jsp page use EL expression?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have a java class like this :

```
class Constans {
    public static final String FIELD = "example";
}
model.addAttribute(Constants.FIELD, 11);
```

Now on the jsp page 
I just want to use like this to access :

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.Constants.FIELD}"/>
```

How should I do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to save this object fe. in session scope:
     setAttribute("FIELD", Constans.FIELD)
you can set this in servlet and call EL expression in jsp page:
     ${FIELD}

You can add to session or request only object. Not a class.
[https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)))

Comment: Hi, we're not in 1999 anymore. To catch up I suggest to read the answer in the duplicate as well.